# Significato di “sdrusolina”

Tags: word-meaning, regional, etymology

Nell'ultima strofa di una poesia di Angelo Maria Ripellino, la n. 84 di *Lo splendido violino verde*, trovo la parola “sdrusolina”:

> Dovrò sempre tenere con me in un cartone,
>   in una smancerosa scatolina,
>   una maschera ardente di bellimbusto e imbroglione,
>   da indossare se appare una sdrusolina,
>   non bussola di speranza, ma stella di perdizione.

Non trovo questa parola in nessun dizionario.

Dal contesto, qui e nell'unico altro esempio che trovo in rete, «Il Signore, in casa del Conte, gli fa sposare istasera una bella sdrusolina per maladetto suo dispetto», da *Il Marescalco* di Pietro Aretino, deduco che sia una figura femminile (una giovinetta? una seduttrice? una nobildonna?), ma non so veramente che cosa significhi.

Qualcuno lo sa, e possibilmente anche l'etimo? (A naso, si direbbe derivata da una forma settentrionale di “sdrucciolo”...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/00388.jpg) dà il significato e l'etimologia di questo termine. Da notare che, tra le citazioni di questa voce, viene anche riportata la definizione del *Vocabolario dell'uso toscano* di Fanfani che appare nella risposta di @gbutters:

> **Ṣdruṣolina,**
>   sf. Tosc. Ragazza vivace e graziosa. 
>       *Aretino*, VI-44: Il Signore, in casa del conte, gli fa spo­sare istasera una bella sdrusolina per maladetto suo di­spetto. 
>   *Fanfani*, *Uso tosc.* [s. v.]: ‘Sdrusolina’: si dice in al­cuni luoghi di Toscana come appellativo carezzevole di fanciulla vispa e graziosa.
>  
>       = Dal nome della principessa *Sdrusolina*, personaggio del romanzo ‘I Reali di Francia’ di Andrea da Barberino.

Quindi, l'origine di questo vocabolo è da cercarsi nel nome di un personaggio femminile de [*I Reali di Francia*](https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-a/andrea-da-barberino/i-reali-di-francia/) di [Andrea da Barberino](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/andrea-da-barberino_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/) (nato verso il 1370), la figlia  del re Balante, che infatti nel romanzo viene chiamata Drusolina.

Answer (score 10):

Sembra che tu abbia ragione sul significato di una figura femminile. Secondo la fonte che ho citato sotto:

[image]

Trascrizione:

> SDRUSOLÍNA. si dice in alcuni luoghi di Toscana come appellativo carezzevole di fanciulla vispa e graziosa.

Viene dal libro: [*Vocabolario dell'uso toscano compilato da Pietro Fanfani*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_Jie4lOTXG0C&pg=PA888&lpg=PA888&dq=sdrusolina&source=bl&ots=xfhPBk4JPc&sig=kyqg3yJajSlmQzfG_Zh1pBgzhjw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=doOIVfaUFIPYggSzwa_IBg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=sdrusolina&f=false)

Comment: Ottimo, grazie! Nessuna idea sull'etimologia?

Comment: @ElementsInSpace: Please don't *substitute* text for images: images are useful. If you like, add a transcription below them.

Comment: @DaG Okay, I understand.

Comment: @DaG What is the use of this image exactly? It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 7):

Anche io ho trovato dei riferimenti della parola alla figura femminile e probabilmente, stando a quello che ho letto, ha in effetti origini toscane.

Nel "Supplimento a' vocabolarj italiani proposto da Giovanni Gherardini: T-Z. 6" dice:

[image]

Trascrizione:

> SDRUSOLÍNA. Sust. f. (*Voce probabilm. del dial. aret.*) *Fanciulla*, *Donzella vispa*, *leggiadra*. Dial. milan. *Sgarzorin.* (Il Duez registra ancor egli questa parola, facendovi corrispondere in francese *Une garce*, *Une coureuse*, cioè *Sgualdrinella*, *Cantoniera*; ma tale non è il valore ch’ella ha nel seg. esempio.) — Il signore in casa del conte gli fa sposare istasera una bella sdrusolina.
> <sub>Aret. Maresc. a. 3, s. 1, p. 258.</sub>

[*Supplimento a' vocabolarj italiani proposto da Giovanni Gherardini: T-Z. 6*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=WnXbcLt72yQC&dq=sdrusolina&hl=it&pg=PA473#v=onepage&q=sdrusolina&f=false)

Secondo il [Vocabolario lucchese](https://books.google.it/books?id=HnUTAAAAQAAJ&q=Vocabolario%20lucchese%20sdrusolina&dq=Vocabolario%20lucchese%20sdrusolina&hl=it&sa=X&ei=MFqJVeP0AqWJygOInZXQAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA) è una variante della parola **drusolina**, con "s intensivo", ma di questa variante non ho trovato altre informazioni.

[image]

Fanno entrambi riferimento al "Marescalco dell'Aretino".

Comment: A chi aveva inserito la trascrizione: attenzione, c'erano vari errori che la rendevano meno utile.

Answer (score 5):

È presente anche nel *World of Words*, il vocabolario italiano-inglese pubblicato da [John (o Giovanni) Florio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Florio) a cavallo tra '500 e '600: la sdrusolina è definita in inglese (nell'ortografia dell'epoca) come

> *a prettie trull, a handsome wench, a slie whore, a quaint wench, used for a nickname for a woman that is light, or slipperie in the heeles* ([fonte](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/florio/500.html)).

Si noti che tra le possibili sfumature si allude (come nella definizione del Gherardini citata in un'altra risposta) più volte al meretricio.

Quello *slipperie* (corrispondente all'odierno *slippery*) fa pensare a un nesso con “sdrucciolare” (quasi una donnina “sgusciante”).